# While loop in zoom animate not executing?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-handler

I'm running a handler inside of a while loop, against a lat/lng span so if i'm outside of a certain span, that map will automatically zoomIn. I'm using this exact same setup, comparing zoom levels instead of spans and it works just fine. Here's what I'm doing...

```
public static void smoothZoomToSpan(final MapController controller,
        MapView v, GeoPoint center, int latitudeSpan, int longitudeSpan) {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final MapView mapView = v;

    final int currentLatitudeSpan = v.getLatitudeSpan();
    final int currentLongitudeSpan = v.getLongitudeSpan();

    final int targetLatitudeSpan = latitudeSpan;
    final int targetLongitudeSpan = longitudeSpan;



    controller.animateTo(center, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            int curLatSpan = currentLatitudeSpan;
            int curLngSpan = currentLongitudeSpan;
            int tarLatSpn = targetLatitudeSpan;
            int tarLngSpan = targetLongitudeSpan;

            long delay = 0;

                while ((curLatSpan - 6000 > tarLatSpn)
                        || (curLngSpan - 6000 > tarLngSpan)) {
                    Log.e("ZoomIn", "Thinks we should!");
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            controller.zoomIn();
                            Log.e("ZoomIn", "Zoomed");
                        }
                    }, delay);

                    delay += 150; // Change this to whatever is good on the
                                    // device
                }
                Log.e("ZoomIn", "completed");
        }
    });
}
```

After I execute this code, Logcat outputs "Thinks we should!" (basically flooding the logs) endlessly. But it never does anything with my handler... the actual zoomIn call never fires, and it just loops forever until I force-close my application. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler and the while loop are both executing their `Runnable`s on the UI thread.  So you've posted a bajillion runnables to the UI thread handler, but it doesn't matter, because the UI thread is busy executing your while loop and never gets to the point where it can execute the runnables you've posted to the handler.  You'll have to modify your flow of control somewhat to get this to work - perhaps something like this:

```
public static void smoothZoomToSpan(final MapController controller,
    MapView v, GeoPoint center, int latitudeSpan, int longitudeSpan) {
  controller.animateTo(center, new Runnable());
}

private class ExecuteZoom implements Runnable {
  static long delay;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    if ((curLatSpan - 6000 > tarLatSpn)
                    || (curLngSpan - 6000 > tarLngSpan)) {
       handler.postDelayed(new ExecuteZoom(), delay);
       delay += 150;
    }
  }
}
```

Clearly not a complete implementation, you might have to pass the constructor of the runnables some variables, etc; but hopefully this works out a bit better for you.

Comment: That sounds like it could be the issue. Can you give an example of a better implementation?

Comment: @RyanInBinary Done - somewhat in the nature of a recursive function - I didn't do everything, but hopefully it will get you going

Comment: This just messed me up even more. I have no idea how to interpret what you've posted. I appreciate the help, but all it did was create a ton of errors for me that I'm unable to work through right now. I'm not looking for a copy/paste answer, but I can't get your code working at all and I don't know enough about this process to integrate it.

Comment: Well we'll skip my posted code then since it would be too hard for us to debug - but the Idea is that when the animateTo function is done, it posts your runnable for execution to the UI thread.  From there, your runnable should zoom, post a new runnable (we'll call it runnable2) to the thread (on a delay).  runnable2 should check and see if it's zoomed in enough, and if it isn't, zoom and post another runnable to the thread, and so on.  Does that clarify at all?